# How to fix these problems installing imgdupes

Tags: python, 15.04, ubuntu-gnome

I'm trying to install imgdupes, but the terminal says pip command not found.

https://github.com/jesjimher/imgdupes

```
sudo apt-get install python-cffi python-dev libjpeg-dev gir1.2-gexiv2-0.10
sudo pip install texttable
sudo pip install jpegtran-cffi
```

I entered:

```
sudo apt-get install python-cffi python-dev libjpeg-dev gir1.2-gexiv2-0.10
```

So why is pip unknown? Shouldn't it be working after that?

I use gnommeubuntu

Thanks.

Comment: I can not see that pip is unknown. I see no error in your question.

Comment: if I enter
    sudo pip install texttable
it says command pip unknown

Comment: Paste the output of `apt-cache policy python-pip` and `apt-cache policy python3-pip`in your question.

Comment: And give me a ping :)

Comment: Do you have `pip` installed? Try installing it with `sudo apt-get install python-pip` and see if the other commands work now.

Comment: By the way, `imgdupes` got renamed to `jpegdupes` and, since it was migrated to Python 3, it's already in Pypi, so it can be directly installed using `pip install jpegdupes`.

Answer (score 1):

- Install pip with this command in a terminal:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-pip
  ```

  run this version with `pip` or `pip2`
- and/or the Python 3 version of the package

  ```
  sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-pip
  ```

  run this version with `pip3`

Comment: The terminal just says that it didn't work, and I should try again

Comment: give me a complete error message.